# Do i always need to explicitly set sub objects while saving Hibernate main Object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, binding

I have Class Person

```
public Person() {
    //passports = new AutoPopulatingList<Passport>(Passport.class); 
    passports = new AutoPopulatingList<Passport>(new PassportFactory(this));
}


@Id
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
@GeneratedValue
 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
public String getFirstName() {
 return firstName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
public String getLastName() {
 return lastName;
}

@Column(name = "MONEY")
public Double getMoney() {
 return money;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
public List<Passport> getPassports(){
      return this.passports;
 }
```

Class Passport

```
@Id
@Column(name = "passport_id")
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getPassport_id() {
    return passport_id;
}

@Column(name = "country_issue")
public String getCountry_issue() {
    return country_issue;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
public Person getPerson(){
    return person;

}
```

It is bi directional onetomany relationship.

Initially i was saving like this

```
session.save(person);
```

and it was not saving person_id in passport table , then someone told me to do this

```
for(Passport passport : person.getPassports())
      {
          passport.setPerson(person);
      }
 session.save(person);
```

By doing that it worked!!.

My question was that if i am using ElementFactory and setting the person object in passport there with

```
public Object createElement(int index) {
    Passport passport = new Passport();
    passport.setPerson(person);
    return passport;
```

Then why i have to explicitly set the person abject again

This the Passportfactory class which i am using in autopopulateList

```
public class PassportFactory implements AutoPopulatingList.ElementFactory {
  private Person person;

  public PassportFactory(Person person) {
     this.person = person;
  }

  public Object createElement(int index) {
    Passport passport = new Passport();
    passport.setPerson(person);
    return passport;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bidirectional associations are handled manually by the user (just like you showed)

Comment: then what is the use case of ElementFactory there. it served no purpose

Comment: @Pasha - in the elementfactory I don't see where the `person` is coming from. It might be an incorrect person, or null.

Comment: @Pasha - can you debug whether 1. it is not null 2. it is the same object that you later save.

Comment: @Pasha - simply put a breakpoint, or System.out, and compare.

Comment: I added the logger.debug(person); in the PassportFactory constructor and in just before Session.save() . they have same id Person@1781288