# Relationship IDs not being set before saving

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an `Order` that has...

```
private Collection<OrderCustomField> orderCustomFields;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Collection<OrderCustomField> getOrderCustomFields() {
    return orderCustomFields;
}

@JsonProperty("CustomFields")
public void setOrderCustomFields(Collection<OrderCustomField> orderCustomFields) {
    this.orderCustomFields = orderCustomFields;
}
```

And `OrderCustomFields` has

```
private Order order;

@ManyToOne
@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
}
```

The `order_id` is not being populated in `OrderCustomField` when the order is saved.  I thought that `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` would handle populating these values.  Is there something that I missed, or does that not work as I thought it did?

Comment: Have you defined `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` for each entity?

Comment: See the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219657/do-i-always-need-to-explicitly-set-sub-objects-while-saving-hibernate-main-objec?rq=1

Comment: mateusz - That stinks, because these objects are being mapped from Jersey.  All of my other associations work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `@PrePresist` worked for me...

```
@PrePersist
public void beforeCreate() {
    if(created == null)
        created = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for(OrderCustomField orderCustomField : getOrderCustomFields())
        orderCustomField.setOrder(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When hibernate needs to store a bidirectional relationship to the database and there is conflicting information (one side references the other but not vice versa) then Hibernate relies on the *owning* side of the relationship.  By specifying `mappedBy="order"` on the `@OneToMany` you are declaring the many side the owning side of the relationship.

If you took that off then the owning side would be the one side of the relationship (this is the default for one-to-many relationships) and you would get the behavior you want.

However, Hibernate recommends you always set both sides of the relationship.  This is because the other half wont get populated until the entity goes to the database and gets reloaded.  In other words, as soon as you turn on the second level cache, you will start to have troubles because the order field will be null until the cache reloads the entity from the database.